# In a Git repository, how to properly rename a directory?

Tags: git, directory, rename

I think it should work to copy the directory to be renamed to a new directory with desired name, and [delete the old directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947430/git-remove-directory), and `git add`,  `git commit` and `push` everything.  But is this the best way?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to tell Git that it's the same directory, just a different name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6628539/how-to-tell-git-that-its-the-same-directory-just-a-different-name)

Comment: As far as Git is concerned, a copy and delete is the same thing as a move.  Git will record both (copy + delete) and (move) the same way.

Answer (score 1942, accepted):

Basic rename (or move):

```
git mv <old name> <new name>
```

Case sensitive rename—eg. from `casesensitive` to `CaseSensitive`—you must use a two step:

```
git mv casesensitive tmp
git mv tmp CaseSensitive
```

([More about case sensitivity in Git…](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17688308/101290))

…followed by commit and push would be the simplest way to rename a directory in a git repo.

Comment: Does it save all the log and statistics?

Comment: @ViliusK if you are dealing with case sensitive directories any easy way i've found is `git rm -rf --cached path/to/your/directories` then re-add and commit

Comment: in my case, from gitbash, i was trying to rename a folder that was not part of a git repository, so in that case simply calling this worked

mv <old name> <new name>

Comment: But why GIT doesnt have a proper support for name change for a package/directory? Why do I even need to create a separate folder. When i change a name of the package shouldnt it take it as a difference and take care of it at the time of commit & push?

Comment: if you have hidden or excluded files that require `-force` to be added to the original repo - they will be skipped using this technique. be sure to check that the file counts match!

Comment: On windows I had to open `git bash` as Admin to make it work.

Comment: If you want to rename only case, just use `git mv -f casesensitive CaseSensitive`

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. For me, I had to first execute `git config core.ignorecase false` and then run the commands in succession or else, for the second part I'd get a `source is empty` error.

Comment: On Windows 10, when renaming a directory, `git mv` would complain: `Rename from [x] to [y] failed. Should I try again? (y/n)` even with Administrator privileges.  The rename only succeeded from the console when I closed a File Explorer window that was viewing the parent directory which contained the directory I was renaming.

Comment: Do you also have to use
mv old_folder_name new_folder_name?
I changed the folder name and then tried changing the git name but got a 
fatal: bad source, source error.

Comment: Similar to @arcain, I had a file open in an editor that locked the file. Double check your open applications (and terminal windows?) when you get `Rename from 'scripts' to 'code' failed. Should I try again? (y/n)` on Windows 10.

Comment: excuse me but this doesn't work, get help page says "In the second form, the last argument has to be an existing directory; the given sources will be moved into this directory.", and this is exactly what it's trying to do, instead of renaming the folder

Comment: I had to ensure my `core.ignorecase` was configured to be `true` on Windows, and in between the two `git mv`s I had to manually rename the directory to the right casing

Comment: This fails for me under Mac OS, with "fatal: source directory is empty" (which is not true). This happens even if I use totally different names.

Comment: It helps if it's a clean *clone* of the repo. At least if you're doing a .net project, I think.  I found that if I had `bin` and `obj` folders present, `git mv` it nested badly.  I ended up with a `<new name>` folder that contained an `<old name>` folder with `bin` and `obj` and a `<new name>` folder that had what should have been in the first `<new name>` folder.  Fresh clone (or possibly a better clean than Visual Studio can do) fixed that.

Comment: @orezvani Sadly no. `git log foo/folder` will show log of the folder, `git mv foo/folder folderNew; git commit ; git log folderNew`  will only show the commit that renamed the folder. I'm still looking for a solution, maybe rewriting logs, like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314652/

Answer (score 196):

If you receive this error: fatal: renaming ‘foldername’ failed: Invalid argument

Try this:

### *nixOS

`git mv foldername tempname && git mv tempname folderName`

### WinOS

`git config core.ignorecase false; git mv foldername tempname; git mv tempname folderName`

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to do a case-change in a directory.

Comment: The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version.  git version 2.11.0.windows.

Comment: @Tim Hardy it can also be run as two separate commands, `git mv foldername tempname` and `git mv tempname folderName`, which should work on Windows.

Comment: this does not work ! the end result will put new 'folderName' folder inside the 'tempname' folder

Answer (score 93):

**1. Change a folder's name from oldfolder to newfolder**

```
git mv oldfolder newfolder
```

**2. If newfolder is already in your repository & you'd like to override it and use:-** *force*

```
git mv -f oldfolder newfolder
```

Don't forget to add the changes to index & commit them after renaming with git mv.

**3. Renaming foldername to folderName on case insensitive file systems**

Simple renaming with a normal mv command(not git mv) won’t get recognized as a filechange from git. If you try it with the ‘git mv’ command like in the following line

```
git mv foldername folderName
```

If you’re using a case insensitive filesystem, e.g. you’re on a Mac and you didn’t configure it to be case sensitive, you’ll experience an error message like this one:

**fatal: renaming ‘foldername’ failed: Invalid argument**

And here is what you can do in order to make it work:-

```
git mv foldername tempname && git mv tempname folderName
```

This splits up the renaming process by renaming the folder at first to a completely different foldername. After renaming it to the different foldername the folder can finally be renamed to the new folderName. After those ‘git mv’s, again, do not forget to add and commit the changes. Though this is probably not a beautiful technique, it works perfectly fine. The filesystem will still not recognize a change of the letter cases, but git does due to renaming it to a new foldername, and that’s all we wanted :)

Answer (score 24):

lots of correct answers, but as I landed here to copy & paste a *folder rename with history*, I found that
this

```
git mv <old name> <new name>
```

will move the *old folder* (itself) to nest within the *new folder*

while

```
git mv <old name>/ <new name>
```

(note the '/')
will move the **nested content** from the *old folder* to the *new folder*

both commands didn't copy along the history of nested files. I **eventually renamed each nested folder individually** ✔

```
git mv <old name>/<nest-folder> <new name>/<nest-folder>
```

Answer (score 16):

You can rename the directory using the file system. Then you can do `git rm <old directory>` and `git add <new directory>` ([Help page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rm.html)). Then you can commit and push.

Git will detect that the contents are the same and that it's just a rename operation, and it'll appear as a rename entry in the history. You can check that this is the case before the commit using `git status`

Comment: hey, but this way, I'll loose whole commit history.

Comment: You can retain it if you use the -follow flag.

Comment: Two commands instead of one, and having to add a flag?  Is this better than git mv in any way?

Comment: @topper No, git mv is just an alias for rm+add. Using git mv is a better solution.

Comment: @topper Note that you'll still have to use --follow to view the history regardless of which method you use to move the file.

Comment: Renaming in the file system before you do the appropriate git actions does have the benefit of allowing you to see the effects of a change within a make file or project build, so you can correct anything that breaks during a rename within the same commit.

Comment: Also, in case you have used the file system without thinking, and then have to fix it so git understands, this is the way to go.

Comment: `git mv` did not work for me, but this worked.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an example for renaming directory.

```
git mv src/dir1/ src/dir2/
```

If you get an error stating `Permission Denied`, you can try

```
git mv src/dir1 src/temp/
git mv src/temp src/dir2
```

Answer (score 4):

From Web Application I think you can't, but you can rename all the folders in Git Client, it will move your files in the new renamed folders, than commit and push to remote repository.

**I had a very similar issue:** 
I had to rename different folders from uppercase to lowercase (like Abc -> abc), I've renamed all the folders with a dummy name (like 'abc___') and than committed to remote repository, after that I renamed all the folders to the original name with the lowercase (like abc) and it took them!

Answer (score 2):

For case sensitive renaming, `git mv somefolder someFolder` has worked for me before but didn't today for some reason. So as a workaround I created a new folder `temp`, moved all the contents of `somefolder` into `temp`, deleted `somefolder`, committed the `temp`, then created `someFolder`, moved all the contents of `temp` into `someFolder`, deleted `temp`, committed and pushed `someFolder` and it worked!  Shows up as `someFolder` in git.

Comment: Imo we don't really need a temp folder, required steps:
1. Rename somefolder to any other name (for example somefolder1)
2. Commit and push changes
3. Rename somefolder1 to someFolder
4. Commit and push changes

Answer (score 2):

I tried with the following command and it didn't work. I was receiving a `fatal: renaming '...' failed: Invalid argument` error.

```bash
git mv oldName NewName
```

Then solved with the following method:

1. First I duplicate the folder I wanted to rename
2. Then I ran the following command to remove the folder

```bash
git rm oldName -r
```

3. Renamed the duplicated folder to `NewName`

Answer (score 2):

Just a heads up, the accepted answer won't work unless you give complete folder paths. Otherwise, you'd get **fatal: bad source** error.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32271289)

Answer (score 2):

**Simple Trick**

You can just rename the directory with any temp name and then rename again and it will work

Comment: This is a great trick! saved a lot of time, thank you

Answer (score 0):

renaming in git is difficult because the index will have to change and the tree object will be created after commit.
I had the problem of renaming **t**emplates to **T**emplates...
I solved the problem by

- copying Templates to templates in bash [cp -r Templates templates ] (git mv  Templates templates **will not work**)
- removing Templates in bash [rm -r Templates ](check that the copying was successful first)
- Removing the Templates file from the index[use "git ls-files -s" to see the index, "git rm  " you can use wildcards  such as git rm Templates/*, continue checking the index]
- Adding the renamed paths to the index ("git add -v ." and check the result with "git ls-files -s"
- Commit  ["git commit -m "renaming ... "
- If you have remotes git push <to wherever origin,

Answer (score -27):

Simply rename the folder. git is a "content-tracker", so the SHA1 hashes are the same and git knows, that you rename it. The only thing that changes is the tree-object.

```
$ rm <directory> // remove the directory
$ git add . // add changes to the git
$ git commit // commit removed directory
```

Comment: This does not work always. It surely did not work for me for sth. like 20% files...