# cannot commit due to the renamed files in .git repository

Tags: git, version-control

I have initialized a directory with git:

```
git init
```

And then added all the files:

```
git add .
```

After that, I manually (through OS) renamed one directory (from `Attr` to `attibutes`).

Then I continued my coding, now that I want to commit the changes, it says:

```
Changes not staged for commit:

deleted Attr/file.jpg
/..... a list of similar files which are in renamed directory
```

How should I solve this problem? I did:

```
git update-index
```

But it did neither work.

Comment: use `git rm` on the old and `git add` on the renamed

Comment: Can I know why do I have received down-votes?

Comment: Downvotes are reserved for questions which fulfill the following definition: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". Handling renames in git is something very basic and a simple google search with the keywords `git`, `rename`, `folder` or `files` should have led to a satisfying answer.
This in turn implies no research effort on your side which probably resulted in the downvotes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In a Git repository, how to properly rename a directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183788/in-a-git-repository-how-to-properly-rename-a-directory)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can debug it as  "git status" -> it will show the staged,modified and untracked file.

1.Here you will find "Attr" in changes to be commited or staged status.So here you apply   "git rm Attr" 
 2. In untracked list you will find newly created or renamed file i.e attibutes. So for untracked files you just apply command "git add attributes".

Now you can commit your changes.