# How to use a folder and file with the same name but different case from github in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, case-sensitive, case-insensitive, ntfs

I want to clone a github repo that uses two different files/folders:

`\packages\` - Folder
`\Packages` - File

However, due to windows not using Case Sensitive File/Directory Names, this isnt working, it gives me the error that the folder cant be renamed because a file already has the same name.

The program that uses this project REQUIRES that there be a no-extension binary text file `Packages` (Its like a giant file full of `control` files (*If you recognize linux debian youll understand*)

But it also requires a folder named `\packages\` to hold the json files containing the config data for each control file within `Packages`

**This question is an updated form of this previous question, which is outdated, and doesnt have an answer that solves the problem**: [Working in git with directories with the same name but different case in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27749219/working-in-git-with-directories-with-the-same-name-but-different-case-in-windows)

Comment: This is a Q&A. I had this really aggravating issue for the past couple days, found an outdated question, and made an updated Q&A for the new windows update

Answer (score 2):

From Windows 10's update in April of 2018, they added a feature to "enable" case-sensitivity on specific directories.
I simply used the command on my github storage directory and now my project works fine.

To use the feature: Open a command prompt window (I dont believe this requires Administrator, it didnt for me)

Copy the full directory path to the folder you want to enable the flag on, type in the console:

`fsutil.exe file SetCaseSensitiveInfo #:\Path\To\Directory\Here enable`

Paste your C:/D:/E: or whatever Drive path into the location above. Then hit enter.

You DO NOT need to restart your computer, the flag seems to take effect **immediately**

Info sourced from: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-enable-ntfs-treat-folders-case-sensitive-windows-10#enable_case_sensitivity_ntfs_windows10