# GitHub Desktop issue regarding uppercase to lowercase

Tags: github, github-desktop

I am using [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) and committed some changes with directory name change from uppercase to lowercase (LIBS>libs), everything passed besides directory name change, on github it show LIBS again.

So my question is: is there a way to change directory name from uppercase to lower case in [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved myself with command line, there is no desktop version solution regarding above issue

[how to rename directory in github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183788/in-a-git-repository-how-to-properly-rename-a-directory)