# Recent Project Name Change, Now Seeing Two Copies of my Project Folder on the Remote

Tags: xcode, git, macos

I am new to Swift development. Seems i am in a naming convention rabbit hole out of the gate.

**Problem**

I recently renamed my project (from lower case to upper case to conform with naming conventions) and now, when I push to the remote, I have two copies of my project folder as illustrated below:

```
Students.xcodeproj
Students <---- here
StudentSummary
StudentDatabaseKit
students <---- here
.DS_Store
.gitignore
LICENSE
Podfile
README.md
```

However, this is not reflected on my local. All assets are under the new, renamed Students folder.

**I Have Tried**

- changed display name in Identity & Type
- changed product name in packaging > settings
- changed Info.plist to upper under Settings > Packaging
- changed lower case path names to upper in filesystem
- changed lower casing in xcscmblueprint

**Worth Noting**

1) It seems that the default generated files are in the new Students folder. The files I created are in the older "students" folder. There is no common files between the two folders.

2) Under Identity and Type (right panel, when I click on the main Students folder), I see a lower cased "students" under Location [Relative to Group]. I understand this can be updated if I click on the folder icon next to it and select the correct (uppercase) folder in Finder. However, I am just seeing files, not folders.

**Desired Outcome**

Appropriate assets under renamed Students folder, removal of lower-case folder.

I am sure this is something silly. Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183788/in-a-git-repository-how-to-properly-rename-a-directory

Comment: Thanks, Dan. That worked perfectly. Didn't realize I needed to move to a temp directory for a case sensitive rename. Much appreciated.