# Github project folder names don't reflect local changes

Tags: android, git, github

I recently changed all of my file names from starting with upper case to lower case, but after pushing the changes to Github, my remote project still has the old folder names. How do I force Github to use lowercase file names?
This is what I mean, first image is my local copy, second is how it appears on Github:

[image: How the folders appear locally][image: How the folders appear on Github]

Comment: Are you sure you pushed onto the same branch as you are navigating in GitHub?

Comment: Yes. Whenever I make changes to an actual file and push, the changes are reflected.

Answer (score 0):

Git's directory tracking is case insensitive. You can perform a little hack to solve your problem. First move your contents to a temp dir and commit. then move back to previous location with lower case directory name, then commit and push.

**Edit**

I found another solution. Check this thread: [In a Git repository, how to properly rename a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183788/in-a-git-repository-how-to-properly-rename-a-directory)