# Express server working locally but crashing on heroku

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, heroku

My Node + Express server is working locally but not on Heroku.

Also worth mentioning I'm using `heroku-postgres` and ran these commands

`heroku run knex migrate:latest -a myAppName`
`heroku run knex seed:latest -a myAppName`

The commands ran successfully and I can see the seeded DB on Heroku.

**What's the issue?**

Now when I try to access the server, it just won't work because of some modules it can't find, but again it works perfectly on my end

I'm also deploying from my development-branch, haven't yet merged to master but that shouldn't be the problem.

Heroku Logs:

```
2019-11-20T19:57:57.678058+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-11-20T19:57:57.524659+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:895
2019-11-20T19:57:57.524683+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2019-11-20T19:57:57.524685+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-11-20T19:57:57.524686+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-11-20T19:57:57.524689+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '../../Users/Middlewares/validateUserID'
2019-11-20T19:57:57.524690+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2019-11-20T19:57:57.524692+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/Issues/Routes/IssueRoutes.js
2019-11-20T19:57:57.524694+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/api/server.js
2019-11-20T19:57:57.524695+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/index.js
2019-11-20T19:57:57.524697+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892:15)
2019-11-20T19:57:57.524698+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:785:27)
2019-11-20T19:57:57.524700+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:19)
2019-11-20T19:57:57.524702+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
2019-11-20T19:57:57.524703+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/Issues/Routes/IssueRoutes.js:6:28)
2019-11-20T19:57:57.524704+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
2019-11-20T19:57:57.524706+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1103:10)
2019-11-20T19:57:57.524707+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:914:32)
2019-11-20T19:57:57.524708+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:822:14)
2019-11-20T19:57:57.524710+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:19)
2019-11-20T19:57:57.524711+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
2019-11-20T19:57:57.524712+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/api/server.js:10:21)
2019-11-20T19:57:57.524713+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
2019-11-20T19:57:57.524715+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1103:10)
2019-11-20T19:57:57.524716+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:914:32)
2019-11-20T19:57:57.524717+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:822:14) {
2019-11-20T19:57:57.524718+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2019-11-20T19:57:57.524720+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [
2019-11-20T19:57:57.524721+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/Issues/Routes/IssueRoutes.js',
2019-11-20T19:57:57.524722+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/api/server.js',
2019-11-20T19:57:57.524724+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/index.js'
2019-11-20T19:57:57.524725+00:00 app[web.1]: ]
2019-11-20T19:57:57.524726+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2019-11-20T19:57:57.533660+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-11-20T19:57:57.534079+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2019-11-20T19:57:57.536043+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! bettercity@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`
2019-11-20T19:57:57.536045+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2019-11-20T19:57:57.536154+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2019-11-20T19:57:57.536817+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the bettercity@1.0.0 start script.
2019-11-20T19:57:57.536821+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-11-20T19:57:57.563676+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-11-20T19:57:57.564106+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-11-20T19:57:57.564508+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-11-20T19_57_57_537Z-debug.log
2019-11-20T19:57:57.659267+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-11-20T19:58:25.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user myEmail@mail.com
2019-11-20T19:59:21.041005+00:00 app[api]: Deploy a1b6ff8e by user myEmail@mail.com
2019-11-20T19:59:21.041005+00:00 app[api]: Release v20 created by user myEmail@mail.com
2019-11-20T19:59:21.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2019-11-20T19:59:22.528003+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-11-20T19:59:26.144682+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2019-11-20T19:59:29.286295+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-11-20T19:59:28.777609+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-11-20T19:59:28.777626+00:00 app[web.1]: > bettercity@1.0.0 start /app
2019-11-20T19:59:28.777628+00:00 app[web.1]: > node index.js
2019-11-20T19:59:28.777629+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-11-20T19:59:29.268829+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-11-20T19:59:29.169740+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:895
2019-11-20T19:59:29.169765+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2019-11-20T19:59:29.169766+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-11-20T19:59:29.169767+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-11-20T19:59:29.169779+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '../../Users/Middlewares/validateUserID'
2019-11-20T19:59:29.169780+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2019-11-20T19:59:29.169781+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/Issues/Routes/IssueRoutes.js
2019-11-20T19:59:29.169782+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/api/server.js
2019-11-20T19:59:29.169783+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/index.js
2019-11-20T19:59:29.169784+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892:15)
2019-11-20T19:59:29.169785+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:785:27)
2019-11-20T19:59:29.169786+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:19)
2019-11-20T19:59:29.169787+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
2019-11-20T19:59:29.169788+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/Issues/Routes/IssueRoutes.js:6:28)
2019-11-20T19:59:29.169789+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
2019-11-20T19:59:29.169790+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1103:10)
2019-11-20T19:59:29.169791+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:914:32)
2019-11-20T19:59:29.169792+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:822:14)
2019-11-20T19:59:29.169793+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:19)
2019-11-20T19:59:29.169794+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
2019-11-20T19:59:29.169795+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/api/server.js:10:21)
2019-11-20T19:59:29.169796+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
2019-11-20T19:59:29.169797+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1103:10)
2019-11-20T19:59:29.169798+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:914:32)
2019-11-20T19:59:29.169799+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:822:14) {
2019-11-20T19:59:29.169800+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2019-11-20T19:59:29.169801+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [
2019-11-20T19:59:29.169802+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/Issues/Routes/IssueRoutes.js',
2019-11-20T19:59:29.169803+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/api/server.js',
2019-11-20T19:59:29.169804+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/index.js'
2019-11-20T19:59:29.169805+00:00 app[web.1]: ]
2019-11-20T19:59:29.169806+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2019-11-20T19:59:29.179485+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-11-20T19:59:29.179812+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2019-11-20T19:59:29.181606+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! bettercity@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`
2019-11-20T19:59:29.181811+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2019-11-20T19:59:29.182146+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2019-11-20T19:59:29.182403+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the bettercity@1.0.0 start script.
2019-11-20T19:59:29.182699+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-11-20T19:59:29.198787+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-11-20T19:59:29.199117+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-11-20T19:59:29.199119+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-11-20T19_59_29_183Z-debug.log
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "bettercity",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "server": "nodemon index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/rodpa715/bettercity.git"
  },
  "author": "Patrick Rodrigues",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/rodpa715/bettercity/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/rodpa715/bettercity#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "helmet": "^3.21.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "knex": "^0.20.2",
    "node": "^13.1.0",
    "pg": "^7.12.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "^10.16.3",
    "npm": "6.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.4",
    "supertest": "^4.0.2"
  }
}
```

**[SOLVED]**

It seems as though GitHub doesn't track folder case-sensitivity change so even when I renamed the folders it didn't work. I copied everything into a new repo and it deployed successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

`const { validateUserID } = require("../../Users/Middlewares/validateUserID");`

to

`const { validateUserID } = require("../../users/Middlewares/validateUserID");`

with a lowercase users
linux is case sensitive and it might be giving issues on a server but not on your machine if you have a mac.

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work, I honestly have no idea. I will try tomorrow by changing my whole structure to be camelcase

Comment: I just commented out the import and removed it from the routes and the problem persisted with other controllers...

Comment: This was it! git just didn't track the changes so I had to copy everything into a new repo, now I'm on to see how I can force git to change that

Comment: just to add - require is case-sensitive and the cache will still treat them as different modules and will reload the file multiple times.

Comment: Okay I just got it working on my main repo by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183788/in-a-git-repository-how-to-properly-rename-a-directory)

Answer (score 1):

Your paths to the routes are incorrect and node cannot find those in the Heroku filesystem.

Work off your current file using like './' so you update to:

```
const authRoutes = require("./../Authentication/Routes/AuthRoutes");
```

Comment: I tried that in combination with the answer about the case sensitive paths and nothing has worked

Comment: I will also just start doing this to be on the safe side, thank you Samuel

Comment: Cool, also - always name files and require in lower case everywhere. `require` is case sensitive if you require('mymodule') and require('myModule') node sees these as two separate components instances