# Github Split my directory into two directories

Tags: c++, git, github

This is my file structure in my C++ Opengl project.

```
build-|
Nade-|
    res-|
        textures-|
        shaders-|
    src-|
        //code
    vendor-|
        //dependencies
```

I have pushed this code to Github using Git.
Over there the file structure is

```
build-|
Nade-|
    res-|
        textures-|
        shaders-|
    src-|
        //only one directory out of many
    vendor-|
        //half of the dependencies
nade-|
    src-|
        //rest of the code
    vendor-|
        //other half of the dependencies
```

Somehow it split the directory `Nade` into `Nade` and `nade`
This is the repository https://github.com/extorc/Nade
None of this problem is observed in the local code.
How can i Fix this?

**I am on Windows**

Comment: Have you been renaming nade to Nade at the begining of your project? Maybe that's where the issue came from

Comment: @JimmySoussan Although i don't remember doing any of that but changing directory names is not coming as changes in my `git status` so maybe i might have done that by mistake

Comment: _None of this problem is observed in the local code._ If you're on Windows then `Nade` and `nade` address the same directory. In Linux (and every other *ix OS), `Nade` and `nade` can be two distinct directories. `git` is prepared for this and can be configured to manage that mess to some degree but at best you care about lower/upper case even if you're on Windows.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat But now , how can this be solved?

Comment: As I already mentioned: _at best you care about lower/upper case even if you're on Windows._ I never faced such an issue in the few fiddlings I did myself with github but I would try to pull the whole repo into a local working tree, repairing it, and "pushing" it again to github. Concerning _repairing it_: Maybe remove all resp. files (with wrong name) from the repo and adding them again.

Comment: FYI: [SO: In a Git repository, how to properly rename a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11183788/7478597)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat Yes i ended up renaming all files in the wrong folder
and reading all submodules in the wrong folder to the right one.